# Não consigo clicar no botão desse site com Python Selenium de jeito nenhum

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo uma automação para uma melhoria de processo no meu trabalho, a idéia é varrer regularmente uma pagina específica e identificar se há um novo item nessa página. Ja postei uma dúvida sobre esse projeto aqui no Stackoverflow e o meu problema era ir para o frame correto do botão, e essa etapa foi superada.
Porém agora existe um botão que é o 'Query' para fazer a pesquisa na página e aparecer se há um novo item, porém esse botão Query é IMPOSSÍVEL de clicar, sempre retorna o erro 'NoSuchElementException' ja tentei muitas coisas, esperando o elemento carregar por 1h, colocando um sleep, findelement por ID, XPATH, fullXPATH e algumas outras opções que seriam possíveis achar esse botão, ele esta no mesmo frame de outros botões que eu consigo interagir, mas esse em específico eu não consigo.

Abaixo segue todos os endereços do botão, mostrando o elemento que ele é, e de nenhuma forma ele funciona.

-A barra onde o botão esta
[image: A Barra onde o botão está]

-O botão
[image: O botão]

-Campo dentro do botão
[image: Campo dentro do botão]

-Imagem da lupa do botão
[image: Imagem da lupa do botão]

-Texto do botão
[image: Texto do botão]

-O Menu lateral esquerdo e essa barra de botões estão no mesmo frame, eu consigo clicar no menu lateral esquerdo, porém não consigo interagir com o a barra de botões, em nenhum deles por nenhum tipo de find_element possível.
[image: Menu esquerdo]

Sou iniciante e tenho muito a aprender, mas ja estou estacionado nesse ítem faz algumas semanas e ainda sem nenhum avanço, toda sugestão é bem vinda.

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo, já passei por um problema semelhante e o que me salvou foi o execute_script, uma função do selenium.webdriver.

Tenta utilizar ela assim se tiver com a versão mais atualizada do Selenium:

```
btn = webdriver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'nexacontentsbox')
webdriver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```

Outra opção caso esteja em uma versão mais antiga:

```
btn = webdriver.find_element_by_class_name('nexacontentsbox')
webdriver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```

Pra utilizar o execute_script é bem simples, você só precisa enviar como parâmetro o primeiro comando a ser executado (No exemplo acima estamos enviando um script com um simples click), e como segundo parâmetro o elemento em que o script vai funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Zé Henrique, tentei utilizar esse comando da forma que você escreveu mas não funcionou, mudei o método de busca mas ainda sim tenho a mesma falha 'AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'find_element'' vou dar uma estudada e aprender essa função e ver se acho a minha solução, valeu pela dica!